# QT: Can't terminate Qprocess in a start/stop push button

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a start/stop push button for starting and killing a process. So here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
QProcess* ping_process = new QProcess(this);

    if ( this->myTimer->isActive() == true ) {
            this->myTimer->stop();
            ui->pushButton->setText("Start");

           //...
            ping_process->start("ping", QStringList() << "8.8.8.8");

        } else {
            this->myTimer->start(500);
            ui->pushButton->setText("Stop");

            ping_process->terminate();
        }
}
```

Starting the process is successful, and changing the text for push button is also successful. But `ping_process->terminate();` is not working. I also tried `kill()` and `close()`, but nothing happened. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case each click on button will be create new QProcess and call start or terminate for him. Not for previcously created QProcess. QProcess must be in member area, like this:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
 ...

private:
...
    QProcess* ping_process;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    ...
    ping_process(nullptr),
    ...
{
    ...
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    if (!ping_process)
    {
        ping_process= new QProcess(this);
    }

    if ( this->myTimer->isActive() == true ) {
        this->myTimer->stop();
        ui->pushButton->setText("Start");

       //...
        ping_process->start("ping", QStringList() << "8.8.8.8");

    } else {
        this->myTimer->start(500);
        ui->pushButton->setText("Stop");

        ping_process->terminate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean I love you! .. Can I contact you outside of here?

Comment: In Skype: midvikus

Comment: other way?... i mean an email if it is possible?

Comment: midvikus@gmail.com